# Set up build.gradle Junit Android tests

Tags: android, testing, gradle, junit

I am begineer in Android test. I am trying execute a Junit test, but it crashes when I load a native library.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    // Unit testing dependencies
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use the Hamcrest matcher library
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // more stuff, e.g., Mockito
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

And when I do

```
static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("a");
    }
```

I obtain `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no a in java.library.path`

My test is in `"src/test/java"` and my native library in `"src/test/jniLibs"`. I suppose than I have to specify Jni libraries path in build.gradle, but how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder to the classpath as shown here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-add-to-a-test-classpath/7083